# Make a scrollpath zigzag

Tags: jquery

I have a scrollpath plugin, but it is a little too crazy. It rotates and goes everywhere. I just want it to zigzag and not rotate. Can anyone show me how to edit the numbers in the code?

```
        $(document).ready(init);

    function init() {
        /* ========== DRAWING THE PATH AND INITIATING THE PLUGIN ============= */

        $.fn.scrollPath("getPath")
            // Move to 'start' element
            .moveTo(400, 50, {name: "start"})
            // Line to 'description' element
    .lineTo(400, 800, {name: "description"})
    // Arc down and line to 'syntax'
    .arc(200, 1200, 400, -Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2, true)
    .lineTo(600, 1600, {
        callback: function() {
            highlight($(".settings"));
        },
        name: "syntax"
    })
    // Continue line to 'scrollbar'
    .lineTo(1750, 1600, {
        callback: function() {
            highlight($(".sp-scroll-handle"));
        },
        name: "scrollbar"
    })
    // Arc up while rotating
    .arc(1800, 1000, 600, Math.PI/2, 0, true, {rotate: Math.PI/2 })
    // Line to 'rotations'
    .lineTo(2400, 750, {
        name: "rotations"
    })
    // Rotate in place
    .lineTo(2400, -700, {
        name: "rotations-rotated"
    })
    // Continue upwards to 'source'
    .lineTo(2400, -700, {
        name: "source"
    })
    // Small arc downwards
    .arc(2250, -700, 150, 0, -Math.PI/2, true)

    //Line to 'follow'
    .lineTo(1350, -850, {
        name: "follow"
    })
    // Arc and rotate back to the beginning.
    .arc(1300, 50, 900, -Math.PI/2, -Math.PI, true, {rotate: Math.PI*2, 
    enter code here name: "end"});

     // We're done with the path, let's initate the plugin on our wrapper 
 element
     $(".wrapper").scrollPath({drawPath: true, wrapAround: true});

     // Add scrollTo on click on the navigation anchors
     ("nav").find("a").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Include the jQuery easing plugin 
    (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)
        // for extra easing functions like the one below
        $.fn.scrollPath("scrollTo", target, 1000, "easeInOutSine");
    });
});

/* ===================================================================== */

$(".settings .show-path").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".sp-canvas").toggle();
}).toggle(function() {
    $(this).text("Hide Path");
}, function() {
    $(this).text("Show Path");
});

$(".tweet").click(function(e) {
    open(this.href, "", "width=550, height=450");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$.getJSON("http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?callback=?&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjoelb.me%2Fscrollpath",
        function(data) {
            if(data && data.count !== undefined) {
                $(".follow .count").html("the " + ordinal(data.count + 1) + " kind person to");
            }
        });
}


   function highlight(element) {
        if(!element.hasClass("highlight")) {
            element.addClass("highlight");
            setTimeout(function() { element.removeClass("highlight"); }, 
    2000);
        }
    }
    function ordinal(num) {
        return num + (
            (num % 10 == 1 && num % 100 != 11) ? 'st' :
            (num % 10 == 2 && num % 100 != 12) ? 'nd' :
            (num % 10 == 3 && num % 100 != 13) ? 'rd' : 'th'
        );
    }
```

How to edit the code and make the divs zig zag all the way to the bottom of the website and make it go very smooth because when I use the buttons, it is very rough and to fast when it scrolls.